# How can I fill a hash with an array of values from another hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, key-value

EDIT 2nd Version for clarity:

I have the following hashes:

sample input ->

```
hashweek={[43,2011]=>[0,0,0],[44,2011]=>[0,0,0],**[45,2011]=>[0,0,0]**,[1,2012]=>[0,0,0],[2,2012]=>[0,0,0]}
timesRealCum={[43,2011]=>1000,[44,2011]=>1100,[1,2012]=>1200,[2,2012]=>1300}
```

expected output ->

```
hashweek={[43,2011]=>[1000,0,0],[44,2011]=>[1100,0,0],**[45,2011]=>[1100,0,0]**,[1,2012]=>[1200,0,0],[2,2012]=>[1300,0,0]}
```

What is pretended is that while iterating through timesRealCum or hashweek, or whatever appropriated methodology, hashweek[0] values should be updated to contain corresponding values from timesRealCum, or if not present in timesRealCum hash, the last significant value.

Comment: To make it clear, can we get a sample input and expected output of what you want? Also, `timesRealCum` is an awkward name choice :p

Comment: Is there a timesFakeCum variable?  ;)

Comment: Bad joke, but should point out that hash_week and times_real_cum style is the more common in Ruby code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should be enough :

```
timesRealCum.each{|k, v| hashweek[k][0] = v}
```

There's no test for nil values so if you expect to have missing keys in hashweek, you'd have to test for `hashweek[k]` presence and `hashweek[k][0]`  :

```
timesRealCum.each{|k, v| hashweek[k][0] = v if hashweek[k] && hashweek[k][0]}
```

Edit: So if I understand correctly, if there's no entry in timesRealCum, you'd like to take the last value assigned while looping on hashweek?

```
last_v = 0
hashweek.each{|k, v| last_v = v[0] = timesRealCum[k] || last_v }
```

Comment: Almost right, but position hashweek[45,2011] remains [0,0,0] and not [1100,0,0] as expected. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, this changes hashweek, I'll paste my output from irb

Comment: Yes, hashweek as been updated, but that week [45,2011] should be [1100,0,0]. Going through my question first version i realized it wasn't explicit. Try to see hashweek[0] as a accumulator for values in timesRealCum, even if that key isn't present in timesRealCum

Comment: ok edited my answer, it should work

Comment: That does it. Thanks for your time and promptness.

Answer (score 0):

Now this one below use inject to keep the accumulative value if timesRealCum doesn't contain the week&year.  Now it returns [1100, 0, 0] for [45, 2011].

```
hashweek.inject(0) do |mem, kv_pair|
  hashweek[kv_pair.first] = [timesRealCum[kv_pair.first]||mem, kv_pair.last[1..-1]].flatten
  mem = hashweek[kv_pair.first][0]
end

p hashweek
#=> {[43, 2011]=>[1000, 0, 0], [44, 2011]=>[1100, 0, 0], [45, 2011]=>[1100, 0, 0], [1, 2012]=>[1200, 0, 0], [2, 2012]=>[1300, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: Same result as Anthony, position hashweek[45,2011] remains [0,0,0] and not [1100,0,0] as expected. Thanks for reply.

Comment: OK, but why hashweek[45, 2011] needs to be [1100, 0, 0] instead of [0, 0, 0].  Couldn't find the algorithm from your description.

Comment: First position of array contains accumulated values over time. While hashweek contains all possible weeks/year, timesRealCum may not contain a value for that week/year.

Comment: @user1826611: the inject sets a local variable to do the trick, should be no harm to your code base.

Comment: Your solution works as well. Thank you for your reply. I accepted Anthony solution since is clearer to me.